# Hiding emacs backup files in Finder

Tags: finder, emacs, file

I would like to find a way to hide all the *~ files in Finder, which are used as backup files by Emacs. Is there a general approach to make Finder hide all the files with their names matching certain patterns? Thanks.

Comment: If you are only concerned about Emacs backup files, would storing them all in a single folder (e.g. `~/.emacs-backups/`) be an option as well?

Comment: @patrix Thank you, I did so. Sometimes, it's easier to customize the Emacs OS than Mac OS:)

Comment: That's truly true. Please post the specific settings for `backup-directory-alist` etc. as the answer so others can benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like all the `#*#` and `*~` files floating around in your working directory, put the following elisp code in your `.emacs` file.

```
;; Put autosave files (ie #foo#) and backup files (ie foo~) in ~/.emacs-backups/.
(custom-set-variables
  '(auto-save-file-name-transforms '((".*" "~/.emacs-backups/autosaves/\\1" t)))
  '(backup-directory-alist '((".*" . "~/.emacs-backups/backups/"))))

;; create the autosave dir if necessary, since emacs won't.
(make-directory "~/.emacs-backups/autosaves/" t)
```

Reference: http://snarfed.org/gnu_emacs_backup_files

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide a file from GUI you can use `chflags` utility, e.g.

```
chflags hidden *~
```

As a permanent solution you can install a `launchd` agent with command

```
find $HOME -type f -name '*~' -exec chflags hidden '{}' ';'
```

I used [Lingon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/files/Lingon/2.1.1/) for that.